# How can I generate correlated Pearson III random variates

Tags: r, correlation, random-variable

I would like to generate correlated Pearson III random variates. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

I can generate independent Pearson III random variates using the rlmomco function in the lmomco package.

Comment: You can always use a copula.  What requirements do you have?  For instance, do you wish to specify the covariance matrix directly?

Comment: Yes.  I'm thinking of a hydrological example where I have two tributaries.  Flood frequencies are specified in each river using the Pearson III distribution and high flows are correlated.  We can estimate the flood frequency distributions and correlation from historic data.

Comment: That's helpful.  Will the variables have the same shape parameters or not?  (These variables are versions of Gamma variables, which can have various shapes; and when the variable shapes differ, not all correlations are possible and your options for generating correlated variables are more limited.)

Comment: Generally they will have different shape parameters.   I'm thinking of a flashy urban stream entering a larger river that as a lot of flood storage.

Comment: Pearson type III is location-shifted Gamma (possibly with a sign-flip). Copulas will be the main, most general approach, but you can also do simple things like take some common component Gamma ($Z$) with smaller shape parameter than either outcome  and unit scale, then let $X_0=U+ Z$ and $Y_0=V+ Z$ where $U,V,Z$ are all independent gammas with unit scale and where $U$ and $V$ have shape parameter chosen to get $X_0$ and $Y_0$ with the right shape, then scale and shift as needed $X=aX_0+b$, etc. This may have the advantage that a common-component approach might be interpretable in your setting.